# What is the correct url syntax for mytheme.css to access items in it's sub-directory?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

The alternative of my gdm3 is installed at [`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/mytheme.css`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178169/how-to-assign-a-priority-number-to-update-alternatives-config-gdm3-css-in-a). It's `assets` directory, which stores all the .svg files,  is located at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets`. A typical selector in `mytheme.css` accesses the .svg files in the "assets" directory like so:

```
.toggle-switch-us {
  background-image: url("assets/toggle-off.svg"); }
  .toggle-switch-us:checked {
    background-image: url("assets/toggle-on.svg"); }
```

However, these svg images (and all the other .svg images) do not seem appear in the gnome greeter and unlockscreen.

What is the proper `url` syntax to declare what I want?