# Default folder to install customised GDM theme

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gdm

In Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that directory `/usr/share/themes` is where customized GTK themes, that beautify the Desktop and Lockscreen, are installed.

For customized GDM theme, i.e. theme use to beautify the GNOME Loginscreen and Unlockscreen, is `/usr/share/themes` also the default directory to install them? Or, is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` the default directory to install customized GDM theme?

Clarification:

- The theme that I want to install is suppose to only change the looks
  of the GDM login and unlockscreen, not the desktop environment. [I
  plan to use it via sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178169/how-to-assign-a-priority-number-to-update-alternatives-config-gdm3-css-in-a) I think
  such a theme should not be found in user directory. Agree? For the
  desktop environment, I will use other user theme to change the look
  and use GNOME Tweaks to configure that.
- So between /usr/share/themes and /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme, which
  directory should I use to install customised GDM theme? I am leaning
  towards the latter. If it is the former, I am concern that the customised GDM theme
  would appear in gnome-tweaks theme and a user can mistakenly select
  it as a desktop theme. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.themes` directory in your home directory. (~/.themes)

Install the `User Themes` GNOME extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/.

Install/move new themes into ~/.themes.

Install `gnome-tweaks`, and select your desired theme there.

Understand that poorly written themes can cause all kinds of problems with your GUI.

**Update #1:**

If you're talking about changes to the gdm3.css file, be forewarned that incorrect changes can lead to log in/out problems, and lock you out of your computer.

Modified .css files should probably be placed into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`.

Comment: The theme that I want to install is suppose to only change the looks of the GDM login and unlockscreen, not the desktop environment.  [I plan use it via sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178169/how-to-assign-a-priority-number-to-update-alternatives-config-gdm3-css-in-a). I think such a theme should not be found in user directory.  Agree?  For the desktop environment, I will use other user theme to change the look and use GNOME Tweaks to configure that.

Comment: @SunBear ah... you're talking about a slightly different kind of theme change than I thought. Be forwarned... the changes that you're considering can easily trigger log in/log out problems, and you may get locked out of your computer. Not recommended.

Comment: Noted. So between `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`, which directory should I use to install customised GDM theme? I am leaning towards the latter. If it is the former, the customised GDM theme would appear in gnome-tweaks theme and a user can mistakenly select it as a desktop theme. Correct?

Comment: The theme that is stored in /usr/share/g...s/theme will never show under tweaks..

Comment: @SunBear if it's a theme, then I'd put it in the .themes folder outlined in my answer. If it's an alternate .css file, I'd maybe put it into /etc/alternatives, or /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ where the other .css files are located.

Comment: Appreciate. I have clarified my question using my comments. Can you revise your answer to reflect your two comments so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @SunBear Done...