# Where does /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css pull its colors from?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gdm, css

I have been changing the `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` file to customize the colors of my desktop for a while now, but I believe it may be making my OS unstable. It even says on the top of the file "This stylesheet is generated, DO NOT EDIT".

So, where are the colors of this file derived? Am I able to modify the source of this color?

Comment: Is it an environment variable?

Comment: instead editing `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` you can install alternatives with this answer and make your changes to that file.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1178169/739431

Comment: yes from source it is possible to assign colors.. what I understood while editing colors from source code is that...roughly you will difine around 10 colors... those colors will make around 100 colors... that's it.. if you edit gdm3.css you will have access to all those 100 colors in different ways like rgb hex with different opacity...the advantage from source is that if you have errors it will not generate the css file.. where as manually editing gdm3.css may break access to GUI but can be easily recovered from above link..so just to change some backgrounds or colors.. above linked mtd easy